# In Ruby, how can I extract a tar archive stream directly to the filesystem?

Tags: ruby, archive, tar

I am using Grit (Ruby gem) to load a git repo, extract a given commit to a folder, then 'do stuff' with it. Grit supports git archive with [archive_tar](http://grit.rubyforge.org/classes/Grit/Repo.html#M000239) which retuns a 'string containing tar archive'. I would like to extract this to the filesystem using Ruby libs / gems if possible (not direct system calls) and avoid things like saving the data to an archive first and then extracting it (really looking for an efficient one-liner here).

Comment: Please show the code that you're using to do this now.

Comment: I didn't really have code to do it before. I just used Grit to make a tar file first and then call tar as a system command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that 'string containing tar archive' is equivalent to

`File.open("Downloads.tar", "rb") {|a| a.read }`

I am able to accomplish this using fileutils, stringio, and the minitar gem.
First you will need to install minitar, which should be as simple as

```
gem install minitar
```

Since minitar does not support it's regular unpack to use a stream, we'll create our own rudimentary unpacking method.

```
require 'archive/tar/minitar'
require 'stringio'
require 'fileutils'

def unpack_tar(directory, string)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(directory) if !File.exist?(directory)
  stringio = StringIO.new(string)
  input = Archive::Tar::Minitar::Input.new(stringio)
  input.each {|entry|
    input.extract_entry(directory, entry)
  }
end

unpack_tar("./test", File.open("Downloads.tar", "rb") {|a| a.read })
```

Of course replacing the whole File.open part with the `archive_tar` function of the Grit gem. This is all assuming that first assumption of course, though i'm sure ths method can easily be adapted to suit whatever `archive_tar` actually returns.

Comment: This worked great using e.g. `Grit::Repo.new('repo_dir').archive_tar('commit_id')` as the string.